# Why Maximum Likelihood Estimation for normal distribution?

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation, bayesian-nonparametric

Since we can compute the mean and the standard deviation of a set of random variables, why do we use  Maximum Likelihood Estimation to estimate these parameters?

Comment: The MLE of a normal RV consists, indeed, in the empirical mean and variance. Where did you encounter the use of MLE to estimate a normal distribution parameters?

Comment: @RomainReboulleau In all materials I checked. See Theodoridis, S., & Koutroumbas, K. “Pattern recognition. ” Fourth Edition, 9781597492720, 2008

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that we can compute the **[sample](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/population-and-sample)** [mean](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/expected-value) and **[sample](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/population-and-sample)** [standard deviation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/standard-deviation) from a set of random variables, the Maximum Likelihood Estimation provides a formal framework for estimating the **[population](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/population-and-sample)** parameters based on observed data.

In most cases, we are more interested in what we can imply for the [population](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/population-and-sample) than what we know about the [sample](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/population-and-sample), this is why we use the estimation, since the [sample](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/population-and-sample) usually has some flaws in how it is created.